# enclosing all JSON Integer Values with double quotes "" using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, json

I have been breaking my head for this solution , I have JSON String as follows

```
{"Nodes":
    [
        {
            "Node_id": 10023
        },
        {
            "Node_id": 10056
        },
        {
            "Node_id":00000
        }
    ],
    "utc":136199375611
}
```

how to convert it to below format

```
{"Nodes":
    [
        {
            "Node_id": "10023"
        },
        {
            "Node_id": "10056"
        },
        {
            "Node_id":"00000"
        }
    ],
    "utc":"136199375611"
}
```

Now i want to encode all the integer values (which ever place in the value) with double quotes "integer value", How do i do it in Regular expression's using java Patterns and matcher class or even a substring class. ur help would be much appretiated.

---

#### EDIT

the original JSON format will be like below

```
{
    "Nodes": [
        {
            "Node_id": "10023",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "Node_id": "10056",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "Node_id": "+00000",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "Node_id": "-00000",
            "count": "6"
        }
    ],
    "utc": "136199375611",
    "DeliveryTime": "Tue 23rd jun 2014 12:45 AM",
    "Ifr": "2333"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick fix.

```
jsonString.replaceAll("(\\d+)","\"$1\"")
```

---

But I suggest you to use proper JSON parser or GSON library to parse it into Java Object then convert Integer values to String and finally convert back that Java Object to JSON string.

[GSON Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

- Convert the JSON String into Java Object using [Gson#fromJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- Convert back to the JSON String from the Java  using [Gson#toJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object%29).

Sample code:

```
class NodesDetail{
    private ArrayList<NoteId> Nodes;
    private String utc;
}

class NoteId{
    private String Node_id;
}

...
NodesDetail obj = new Gson().fromJson(reader, NodesDetail.class);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(obj));
```

output:

```
{
  "Nodes": [
    {
      "Node_id": "10023"
    },
    {
      "Node_id": "10056"
    },
    {
      "Node_id": "00000"
    }
  ],
  "utc": "136199375611"
}
```

---

#### EDIT

just edit the POJO class to match as per the JSON string

```
class NodesDetail{
    private ArrayList<NoteId> Nodes;
    private String utc;
    private String DeliveryTime;
    private String Ifr;
}

class NoteId{
    private String Node_id;
    private String count;
}
...
NodesDetail obj = new Gson().fromJson(reader, NodesDetail.class);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(obj));
```

output:

```
{
  "Nodes": [
    {
      "Node_id": "10023",
      "count": "1"
    },
    {
      "Node_id": "10056",
      "count": "2"
    },
    {
      "Node_id": "+00000",
      "count": "1"
    },
    {
      "Node_id": "-00000",
      "count": "6"
    }
  ],
  "utc": "136199375611",
  "DeliveryTime": "Tue 23rd jun 2014 12:45 AM",
  "Ifr": "2333"
}
```

Comment: THanks for your quick reply, @Braj Now i have the real scenario like this , the original JSON format will be like below ,  '{ 
  "Nodes": [
    {
      "Node_id": "10023",
      "count":1
    },
    {
      "Node_id": "10056",
      "count":2
    },
    {
      "Node_id": "+00000",
      "count":1
    }
    {
      "Node_id": "-00000",
      "count":"6"
    }
  ],
  "utc": "136199375611",
  "DeliveryTime":"Tue 23rd jun 2014 12:45 AM",
  "Ifr":"2333"


}' , if i now do the str replace , some were right and some were wrong , for this one how will you do it with regular expressions. Thanks in adV

Comment: Please post it in your question as an edit in the end.

Comment: Just add it in the end don't replace existing text.

Comment: thank you so much , can u pls help me in doing with Regular expressions , in java

Comment: sure why not but you have to post separate question on it because that's off topic from this question.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if the issue is solved. visit [tour](http://stackoverflow/tour)

Comment: How to accept this answer for it @Braj, i could not find an option like that  , iam new to it.

Comment: there is a green right mark click on it. and [visit](http://stackoverflow/tour) to learn more.